# Kernel panic under DDOS

Tags: networking, debian, kernel, ddos

I'm running a Debian 6 - 64bit system (Kernel 2.6.32-5-amd64) and often get flooded with DDOS. I have tuned the network parameters under **/etc/sysctl.conf** to not let any kernel parameter overflow. Although much of the parameters were fine but I started observing the "nf_conntrack: table full" messages in ** /var/log/messages**, so to get over that, I added some further optimizations and increased the parameters. Here are some outputs from "**sysctl -a**",

```
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max = 256000
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_count = 124
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_buckets = 256000
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_generic_timeout = 120
kernel.printk_ratelimit = 30
kernel.printk_ratelimit_burst = 200
```

This took care of the "nf_conntrack: table full" messages for a while but now I'm getting the following messages constantly and often my system becomes unresponsive to its network. I see a few "**nf_conntrack: table full**" messages again as well along with a spam of "**dst cache overflow**",

http://paste.ubuntu.com/10748348/

The attack I'm getting is not high enough but the attacker floods me with around 30k PPS continuously for hours that causes this.

These outputs might be useful as well,

```
grep . /proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/*
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/error_burst:1250
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/error_cost:250
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/gc_thresh:131072
```

Comment: Have you considered putting filtering in front of your server?

Comment: What kind of filtering? I block most floods using iptables rules and they work fine but however, the packets still enter the system.